# Creating a bootable iso image from my current installation

Tags: ubuntu, iso, root-filesystem, distributions, mkisofs

We have an old physical machine with *Ubuntu distro 20.04* and that physical machine has a total of `103GB /root partition` and `10GB as swap memory`.  We have currently utilized up to 45GB. We want to create a bootable ISO image from that current installation.

Also, we tried to create an image using the below packages. While running these packages, we are facing an error -- “filesystem.squashfs size exceeds more than 4GB”. Then we verified that the filesystem file consumes more than 8GB. So that, we cannot able to create an image file. Is there any other package/tool to create an image from the current installation? Thanks!

1.remastersys – respin - https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-build-the-own-ubuntu-iso/

2.distroshare image builder - https://github.com/Distroshare/distroshare-ubuntu-imager

Comment: Have you tried [BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MakeALiveCD/DVD/BootableFlashFromHarddiskInstall)?

Comment: @GAD3R Thanks! No, we will check and get back to you

Comment: `@GAD3R` This method also created a filesystem.squashfs size more than `4GB`. [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/166Q1PuN3SFdhDvC7q_khyVqJAFYuU0rh/view?usp=sharing) for your reference.. Any ideas?

Comment: Still need solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script. Pay attention to the notes.
You will have to put it on a USB to make it bootable. Balena etcher will work for the iso. The iso will be in the LIVE_BOOT folder created by the script. Use balena etcher and a USB stick or external hard drive large enough to put the image on something usable. You can also mount as a loopback device. There are decent instructions online for installing a live system and/or making one persistent.

Save script in a text file and run it. Name the text file something like makelive then "chmod +x makelive" then "./makelive"
You can change the names of things beforehand as well by changing the variables just under the notes. Enjoy!

```
#!/bin/bash
# Will create live iso from currently installed Debian system
#
# Make sure these are installed before starting this script
# Depends: rsync live-boot systemd-sysv debootstrap squashfs-tools xorriso isolinux syslinux-efi grub-pc-bin grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-ia32-bin mtools dosfstools resolvconf 
# 
# Run script as root or under su in terminal
# Variables for computer name, iso name and volume label
HOSTNAME=debian-live
ISONAME=debian-live
LABEL=DEBLIVE
mkdir -p $HOME/LIVE_BOOT $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot &&
rsync -aAXv --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found,$HOME/LIVE_BOOT/*} /* $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot &&
printf "" > $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot/etc/fstab && printf "" > $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot/etc/resolv.conf &&
echo "$HOSTNAME" > $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot/etc/hostname &&
mkdir -p $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/{staging/{EFI/BOOT,boot/grub/x86_64-efi,isolinux,live},tmp} &&
mksquashfs $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/live/filesystem.squashfs -e boot &&
cp $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot/boot/vmlinuz-* $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/live/vmlinuz && cp $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot/boot/initrd.img-* $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/live/initrd &&
touch $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/isolinux/isolinux.cfg  &&
printf "UI vesamenu.c32\n\nMENU TITLE Boot Menu\nDEFAULT linux\nTIMEOUT 600\nMENU RESOLUTION 640 480\nMENU COLOR border       30;44   #40ffffff #a0000000 std\nMENU COLOR title        1;36;44 #9033ccff #a0000000 std\nMENU COLOR sel          7;37;40 #e0ffffff #20ffffff all\nMENU COLOR unsel        37;44   #50ffffff #a0000000 std\nMENU COLOR help         37;40   #c0ffffff #a0000000 std\nMENU COLOR timeout_msg  37;40   #80ffffff #00000000 std\nMENU COLOR timeout      1;37;40 #c0ffffff #00000000 std\nMENU COLOR msg07        37;40   #90ffffff #a0000000 std\nMENU COLOR tabmsg       31;40   #30ffffff #00000000 std\n\nLABEL linux\n   MENU LABEL Debian Live [BIOS/ISOLINUX]\n   MENU DEFAULT\n   KERNEL /live/vmlinuz\n   APPEND initrd=/live/initrd boot=live\n\n   LABEL linux\n   MENU LABEL Debian Live [BIOS/ISOLINUX] (nomodeset)\n   MENU DEFAULT\n   KERNEL /live/vmlinuz\n   APPEND initrd=/live/initrd boot=live nomodeset\nEOF" > $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/isolinux/isolinux.cfg &&
touch $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/boot/grub/grub.cfg &&
printf "insmod part_gpt\ninsmod part_msdos\ninsmod fat\ninsmod iso9660\n\ninsmod all_video\ninsmod font\n\nset default=\"0\"\nset timeout=30\n\n# If X has issues finding screens, experiment with/without nomodeset.\n\nmenuentry \"Debian Live [EFI/GRUB]\" {\n    search --no-floppy --set=root --label $LABEL\n    linux (\$root)/live/vmlinuz boot=live\n    initrd (\$root)/live/initrd\n}\n\nmenuentry \"Debian Live [EFI/GRUB] (nomodeset)\" {\n    search --no-floppy --set=root --label $LABEL\n    linux (\$root)/live/vmlinuz boot=live nomodeset\n    initrd (\$root)/live/initrd\n}\nEOF" > $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/boot/grub/grub.cfg &&
cp $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/boot/grub/grub.cfg $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/EFI/BOOT/ &&
touch $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/tmp/grub-embed.cfg &&
printf "if ! [ -d \"\$cmdpath\" ]; then\n    # On some firmware, GRUB has a wrong cmdpath when booted from an optical disc.\n    # https://gitlab.archlinux.org/archlinux/archiso/-/issues/183\n    if regexp --set=1:isodevice '^(\([^)]+\))\/?[Ee][Ff][Ii]\/[Bb][Oo][Oo][Tt]\/?$' \"\$cmdpath\"; then\n        cmdpath=\"\${isodevice}/EFI/BOOT\"\n    fi\nfi\nconfigfile \"\${cmdpath}/grub.cfg\"\nEOF" > $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/tmp/grub-embed.cfg &&
cp /usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isolinux.bin "${HOME}/LIVE_BOOT/staging/isolinux/" && cp /usr/lib/syslinux/modules/bios/* "${HOME}/LIVE_BOOT/staging/isolinux/" &&
cp -r /usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi/* "${HOME}/LIVE_BOOT/staging/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/" &&
grub-mkstandalone -O i386-efi --modules="part_gpt part_msdos fat iso9660" --locales="" --themes="" --fonts="" --output="$HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/EFI/BOOT/BOOTIA32.EFI" "boot/grub/grub.cfg=$HOME/LIVE_BOOT/tmp/grub-embed.cfg" &&
grub-mkstandalone -O x86_64-efi --modules="part_gpt part_msdos fat iso9660" --locales="" --themes="" --fonts="" --output="$HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI" "boot/grub/grub.cfg=$HOME/LIVE_BOOT/tmp/grub-embed.cfg" &&
(cd $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging && dd if=/dev/zero of=efiboot.img bs=1M count=20 && mkfs.vfat efiboot.img && mmd -i efiboot.img ::/EFI ::/EFI/BOOT && mcopy -vi efiboot.img $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/EFI/BOOT/BOOTIA32.EFI $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/EFI/BOOT/BOOTx64.EFI $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/boot/grub/grub.cfg ::/EFI/BOOT/) &&
xorriso -as mkisofs -iso-level 3 -o "${HOME}/LIVE_BOOT/$ISONAME.iso" -full-iso9660-filenames -volid "$LABEL" --mbr-force-bootable -partition_offset 16 -joliet -joliet-long -rational-rock -isohybrid-mbr /usr/lib/ISOLINUX/isohdpfx.bin -eltorito-boot isolinux/isolinux.bin -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table --eltorito-catalog isolinux/isolinux.cat -eltorito-alt-boot -e --interval:appended_partition_2:all:: -no-emul-boot -isohybrid-gpt-basdat -append_partition 2 C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B ${HOME}/LIVE_BOOT/staging/efiboot.img "${HOME}/LIVE_BOOT/staging"
chmod 755 $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/$ISONAME.iso
rm -r $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/staging/
rm -r $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/chroot/
rm -r $HOME/LIVE_BOOT/tmp/
```

Comment: If it will not make the ISO for some reason comment out the last 5 lines.
In the LIVE_BOOT/staging folder you will have boot, EFI, isolinux and live folders. 
Format an external drive as ext4 and mark the boot flag
copy the boot, EFI, isolinux and live folders to the root of the USB/external as well as the efiboot.img
It should boot.

Comment: 1. If the script fails for some reason after the lo...ong running rsync, the chroot folder gets deleted. When you restart, the rsync has to run again. 2. In my case the failure was due to the absence of etc/resolv.conf.